Does Debian provide a method to install and enable the `schedutil` governor?
I want to enable Energy Aware Scheduling to play around with it. How can I try it? When I run cpupower frequency-info --governors I do not see schedutil listed. I am using Debian Bookworm. Is there a way to install and enable the schedutil governor, or is there a kernel packaged with that available?
$ cpupower frequency-info --governors
analyzing CPU 0:
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave

The full output of cpupower info, shows
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 5.10 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 5.10 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 800 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes


schedutil is enabled by default on Debian, and I see many more governors: “ondemand powersave conservative userspace performance schedutil”. Are you using a VM or running on bare metal?

@StephenKitt Bare metal uname -a, Linux cow 6.1.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.99-1 (2024-07-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Your CPU is doing the frequency scaling itself; you can see that by the intel_pstate driver being used.
If you want to do that in software instead, you mustn't allow autonomous frequency scaling. You can do that using intel_pstate=disable on the kernel command line.
However, note that it's not that common that schedutil scaling works better than just letting the CPU do the scaling itself; in the end, you're hoping that having a "slightly better strategy" when scaling beats having "significantly lower latency between deciding you should scale and the scaling happening" in terms of either saving power or getting more performance at same (or comparable power). Wouldn't bet on that, unless you really know your workload cooperates with schedutil well.
In any case, don't do fancy performance things without benchmarking it! Really think of a way of measuring your performance in both settings; and revert manual optimizations that yielded no benefit by default.

Is disabling it fully any 'better' than using intel_pstate=passive in this kind of situation? From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html my impression is that schedutil should be able to control intel_pstate in passive mode with probably better results than basic cpufreq

can't tell you, would have to benchmark your specific workloads.
